# Кастомный ProgressBar

Tags: android, xml

Как мне сделать ProgressBar таким же, что и на картинке. Т.е собственный стиль, но анимация такая же, что и на картинке.

(Желательно без использования сторонних библиотек, если такое возможно)
[image: ProgressBar]

Comment: изучите статейку: http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/views/progressbar.php

Comment: Что мне нужно, там я не смог найти, увы. Я знаю как поставить стандартный ProgressBar, но мне нужно сделать свой стиль, но чтобы анимация соответствовала той, что на картинке.

Comment: Вам стоит определиться что именно вы хотите - изменения цвета стандартного ProgressBar или же точное математическое повторение приведённой анимации. Вполне возможно, что если вы просто стандартный ProgressBar  будете кастомизировать по цвету, то он на разных версиях ОС будет показвать разную анимацию. Если это ОК - просто ищите как менять цвет. По идее - в одну строку это должно делаться. Если нужна именно анимация, то, возможно, придётся ни один день её пилить, подгоняя разные коэффициенты для длительности тактов анимации etc.

Comment: Мне нужна анимация, да. Как же её примерно делать?